# Set QStatusBar minimum height per stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qstatusbar

Is there a way to set a minimum height for a `QStatusBar`

1. Docu says `QStatusBar`only supports color
2. I have tried `QStatusBar::item`
3. also `QStatusBar QLabel`

Is there a way to force a minimum size of `QStatusBar` (per stylesheet)?

Comment: Why do not you use setFixedHeight() or something similar?

Comment: because "hard-coding" it would require to change the C++ code when the stylesheet is being adjusted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me:

`ui->statusBar->setStyleSheet("QStatusBar {min-height: 50; background-color: black; }");`

[image]